# Inheriting permissions with ACLS

Tags: acl, cvs

I've trying to set up a CVS repository using ACL's (setfacl) and having trouble getting permissions to inherit properly. Namely, when a user commits to the repository, I want the file to inherit the acl's of the parent folder. However, using the -d option on the parent seems to cause issues with the read/write lock files that are automatically created by the CVS. Is it possible to do this with standard acl mechanisms?

Thanks